# forgot appleid and password while downloading iOS 9,

Tags: icloud

my iPhone 4s is not working while downloading iOS 9. I forgot Apple ID and password, I have serial no, ime no. and ICCID no of my phone, can Iu solve problem?

Answer (score 1):

First, open up iTunes you activated your iPhone before first usage. Within the account settings, you should see your AppleID name. If you have lost your password, then do a password recovery at iforgot.apple.com.

Second, if that doesn't help, you have to go to the next available AppleStore or contact Apple.